# problems exporting signed release APK with intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 11 CE (which is fantastic by the way), but I'm having trouble exporting a signed APK. My proguard.cfg file works just fine when I export the same exact project using Eclipse. I believe the problem is the way that jars are added the path. When you use ant to build, it requires the jars to be in "libs". IntelliJ, when you add dependencies, adds them to a "lib" folder. So right now my project structure looks like it does in the attached picture. [image: Ignore those PNGs ;)]

As you can see, this was originally an eclipse project so I had /libs and in IntelliJ I kept them there, but removed them from build path. Ok, so the issue is when I try to use the tools to export signed APK, I get proguard errors saying that I have duplicate class definitions. All the settings in my proguard.cfg work perfectly in Eclipse.

Someone, please help me free myself from Eclipse entirely!!

EDIT -

I've configured IDEA to use my /libs folder, but still have problems with Proguard. Here's my errors:

[image]

And here's my dependencies tab with the whole libs folder just lopped in there a dependency. [image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I wanted to the same question myself, but found your post. I am also trying to free myself from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [configure IDEA to use libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) from the same folder as Eclipse does (**libs**) and delete **lib** folder.

Exporting signed APK will invoke Proguard if there is `proguard.cfg` file in the project. In IDEA 11.0.1 you'll be able to skip this step. If you want to skip it in the current version, remove/rename this cfg file.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, you always come through on all things IDEA. So just add all the stuff in libs as Project libraries existing in the current project?

Comment: Still confused about the process for just adding all the stuff in /libs as dependencies...

Comment: Got it to work! Went to project structure > libraries > add > java > pointed to libs folder!

Comment: Still having issues with proguard. I posted a snapshot in my edited question above...

Comment: Right, but you don't need to include JUnit into production classpath, set it's scope to Test or configure Proguard to explicitly exclude it.

Comment: And how do I change the scope? ;)

Comment: But right now my dependencies tab looks as above ^ with the entire /libs in there as a dependency.

Comment: Does the obfuscation work from Eclipse? You may need to configure several libraries, one for tests and another for production and include individual jars into libraries so that you can set different scope. But I guess the problem is with the Proguard configuration file not excluding libraries that are not needed in production (JUnit).

Comment: I have my libs folder specified under the Project Settings > Libraries tab.  It still does not resolve this issue.